# Robots.txt never downloaded but some blocked URLs in GWT

Tags: google-search-console, robots.txt

There is something I don't understand in Google Webmaster Tools (GWT) for my WordPress site.

In menu "Blocked URLs", it mention that my *robots.txt* has never been downloaded but there are some blocked URLs. It's kind of weird and not logical. Am I missing something?

```
User-agent : *
Disallow: /*?
Disallow: /wp-login.php
Disallow: /wp-admin
Disallow: /wp-includes
Disallow: /wp-content
Allow: /wp-content/uploads
Disallow: */trackback
Disallow: /*/feed
Disallow: /*/comments
Disallow: /cgi-bin
Disallow: /*.php$
Disallow: /*.inc$
Disallow: /*.gz$
Disallow: /*.cgi$
Disallow: /author/*
```

I'm afraid my *robots.txt* doesn't block several URLs I want to block.

Edit (screenshot):
[image]

Comment: And GWT states "blocked **by robots.txt**"?! Have you run your robots.txt file through Google's tester, in GWT? You are using a lot of Google-only robots.txt directives - this might not work with other search engines/bots.

Comment: In GWT, in menu "Health" => "Blocked URLs", there is a table with four columns named "robots.txt file", "Blocked URLs", "Downloaded" and "Status". First column contains "http://my-website.com/robots.txt", second one contains "3", third one contains "Never" and fourth one contains nothing.

Comment: It's not mentioned "blocked by robots.txt". I tested robots.txt in Google's tester and it works well. It's just like Google bot found my robots.txt but it mentions that it has never been downloaded!?

Comment: Peculiar. That number "3" indicates URLs that have been blocked by robots.txt (hover over the `?` next to the column title). How long has your current robots.txt file been 'live'? Is it possible there was a previous robots.txt file that blocked these URLs?

Comment: You're right, when I hover `?`, I have this text: "Google tried to crawl these URLs in the last 90 days, but was blocked by robots.txt". I don't understand why Google mention my robots.txt has never been downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem comes from encoding of the *robots.txt* file. `UTF-8` encoding is recommended by Google.

Answer (score 1):

It may just be a glitch – they do happen from time to time.

One other possibility occurs though: your screenshot is from GWT on a non-`www` version of your domain. Do you have the `www` version authorised as well (e.g., so that you can set preferred domain)? If so, and the `www` version is canonical, it could explain why Google would know how many URLs are blocked without *technically* having downloaded the file (they downloaded the `www` version… which *is* the same file really, but isn't in a pedantic techie sense).

Bit of a long shot, but that's about the only explanation, other than a glitch, I can come up with.

Comment: Indeed, this is `no-www` domain. The `www` version is redirected by 301 to `no-www`. However, I didn't choose preferred domain in Webmaster Tools because the functionality doesn't work. Moreover, I don't think blocked URLs are `www` URLs. I blocked by robots.txt many URLs to avoid duplicate content.

Comment: Do you actually have GWT verified on both `www` and non-`www` though? Incidentally, `robots.txt` wouldn't normally reference full URLs, so should apply to both `www`/non-`www`.

Comment: I didn't verify `www` and `no-www`. I did it yesterday and I always have 'Never' in Downloaded column. Can I wait a little to see time data in this colum?

Answer (score 0):

Google will sometimes say it's been blocked by robots.txt when in fact it is a `noindex` tag preventing Google from indexing the page. If you have any plugins for maintenance mode or others which can possibly set `noindex` on your home page or other pages I would suggest you go to the page view the source in your browser and check that there is no `noindex` being rendered by a plugin.

Comment: Thanks Anagio but there is no "noindex" tag on my pages. I edit my question with a screenshot of webmaster tools.